# How do i make this table display only 10 rows when i have more, and how to display others when i search?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I used this table: [jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52ak9/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52ak9/1/) and don't know how to have more rows but display only 10 and to be searchable..

```
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>

    <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Default</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
        <tr>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td>EURO</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>Pound</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GEL</td>
            <td>Georgian Lari</td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>US Dollar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function ($) {

        $('#filter').keyup(function () {

            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();
            $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();

        })

    }(jQuery));

});
```

Please help

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/ might be what you're looking for.

Comment: What you are asking is very unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert your row with

```
.row-class:nth-child(n+10){
    display:none;
}
```

and when found a row/s by filter input change the visibiliti at `display:block`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

you have to just change the limit on sql query an ajax page

for example,

```
$search="test";
if(isset($search)) 
{
  select * from tblname where col_name like %$search%;
} 
else
{
  select * from tblname where limit 0,10;
}
```